# Grouping taking into account field names vice versa

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table #test (name1 varchar(100), name2 varchar(100))
insert into #test values ('Marie','ian')
insert into #test values ('Ian','Marie')
```

and the SQL below:

```
select count(*) from #test group by name1,name2
```

This correctly returns to rows:

```
1,
1
```

How can I return 1 row:

```
2
```

id1 and id2 are the same the other way round so they should be treated as one row.  I believe this may be possible with a CHECKSUM but I am unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM #test 
GROUP BY IIF(name1 >= name2, name1, name2), IIF(name1 < name2, name1, name2)
```

With `CASE` syntax (SQL Server 2008 R2 or earlier):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM #test 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN name1 >= name2 THEN name1 ELSE name2 END, 
         CASE WHEN name1 < name2 THEN name1 ELSE name2 END
```

This way pairs like `('Bob', 'Martin')` and `('Martin', 'Bob')` are treated the same by the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  However, I was not expecting an answer like that.  I have amended the question.  Some of the fields in question are varchars.  Sorry.

Comment: @w0051977 It doesn't matter weather fields are `int` or `varchar`. Solution is still valid.

Comment: I agree with @GiorgosBetsos, who has a very nice, efficient solution. My only suggestion is that you either make sure `name1` and `name2` cannot be `null` or you make sure that `null` values are accounted for in the `CASE` statements.

Comment: IIF is a new concept for me and one I will find very useful.  +1.